# Unable to install npm in react-native

Tags: react-native, npm

*I try to install npm in react-native however it gives me this error:*

[image]

*i can install npms in other project but i cant install for this project why ?*

Comment: Why install the npm in the React-native?

Comment: what ?? forexample;  I try to install npm install --save redux-thunk it gives error which is above

Comment: Are the statements executed within the project folder?

Comment: yes in project folder

Comment: Could you try this? `npm install redux-thunk --save-prod`